# testing a post request having sso creds in java?

Tags: java, post, testing

We have a page which has a searchvfeature which utilizes post request. The website uses sso login to authenticate. HOW can I test the post request  in java

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools out there that don't care about which platform (Java, C#, PHP...) you use.  A few examples are:

- [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-short/mkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef?hl=en).
- [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/working-with-rest-requests.html).
- [HTTest](http://htt.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/cwiki/bin/public).

Some are free, some you have to purchase, and some have limited functionality if you don't purchase the full version; but may still work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found out these things but i want to know how can this be done with a request having sso authentication?